# How to run a ps1 script with parameters inside PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a script that is really basic, it checks to see if certain lister values are null and if they are they are to run a ps1 script in another location. I can get this to work just fine. The problem I have is there are parameters that I need to include when running the other script.

```
$winRM = Get-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config/listener -SelectorSet @{Address="*";Transport="https"}
$winRMPort = $winRM.Port
$winRMTransport = $winRM.Transport
$winRMThumbprint = $winRM.CertificateThumbprint
if(($winRMPort -eq $null) -and ($winRMTransport -eq $null) -and ($winRMThumbprint -eq $null)){
    & "\\myLocation\Scripts\ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1 #These parameters are the part in question -DisableBasicAuth -CertValidityDays 20 -ForceNewSSLCert"
}
else{
    $false
}
```

There are parameters in the other script that work just fine but when I run it in PowerShell it doesn't work.

```
Param (
    [string]$SubjectName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
    [int]$CertValidityDays = 1095,
    [switch]$SkipNetworkProfileCheck,
    $CreateSelfSignedCert = $true,
    [switch]$ForceNewSSLCert,
    [switch]$GlobalHttpFirewallAccess,
    [switch]$DisableBasicAuth = $false,
    [switch]$EnableCredSSP
)
```

I just need to know what I am doing wrong and how to actually pass these parameters without it having issues. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "doesn't work", doesn't help us help you. What doesn't work about it? Getting any errors? Nothing sticks out to me on why that wouldn't work

Comment: Sorry when I run the script it doesn't add the listeners back to the host. Without the parameters it does. I get this error....
The service cannot find the resource identified by the 
resource URI and selectors.

Comment: The problem seem to be that you're wrapping the path as well as the parameters you want to use between `"..."`, you need to wrap only the path! like this: `& "path\to\myps1.ps1" -myparam1 hello -myparam2 world`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon you are amazing. I can't believe I didn't figure that out. Thank you so much